# Scrapy download MIME type file after form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, scrapy, mime

In page http://comunicacion.movistarplus.es/guiaProgramacion/exportarProgramacion there is a form where the user has to type some fields to download the channel schedule for the most important Spanish broadcasters. Once the user fills the form and clicks on the **Exportar** button, the browser automatically starts downloading a file with the extension in **formato** dropdown list.

Now, from my Chrome browser it is very easy to get the file. However, I want to automatise this with a Scrapy script and below you can find what I have done so far:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

class ProgramacionSpider(Spider):
    name = "Programacion"
    allowed_domains = ["comunicacion.movistarplus.es"]
    start_urls = ["http://comunicacion.movistarplus.es/guiaProgramacion/exportarProgramacion"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formname='formExportar', formdata={"fechaInicio": "2017-01-05", "fechaFin": "2017-01-19", "genero" : "0", "selPredefinicion": "0", "formato": "csv", "cadena[]": "{INTECO, ETB}"}, callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        print response
```

Now, after doing a *FormRequest.from_response* with the POST parameters that need to be sent along with the form, **Scrapy** responds with the following text:

```
2017-01-05 13:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.2 started (bot: Programacion)
2017-01-05 13:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Programacion.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'sss.csv', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Programacion.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'Programacion', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'}
2017-01-05 13:19:11 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://comunicacion.movistarplus.es/guiaProgramacion/exportarProgramacion> (referer: None)
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://comunicacion.movistarplus.es/guiaProgramacion/exportar> (referer: http://comunicacion.movistarplus.es/guiaProgramacion/exportarProgramacion)
<200 http://comunicacion.movistarplus.es/guiaProgramacion/exportar>
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 822,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 6603,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 12, 19, 12, 783383),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 12, 19, 12, 204111)}
2017-01-05 13:19:12 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Clearly, the crawler seems to work ok because it doesn't respond with a 500 Error (i.e. it accepts the **POST** variables from the form).

**PROBLEM**

I would like to know how to download the file directly with **Scrapy**, and do not have a single idea on how to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are talking is in the response you are receiving, to be more exact it's in `response.body` attribute.

You can simply open up a file and write the contents of `response.body` into it. Like so:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # check if response is valid
    if response.status != 200:
        print("failed to get schedule")
        return
    # save to file valid response
    with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

Edit: I found an issue with your formdata that was the reason behind empty file being returned:

```
def parse(self, response):
    formdata={"fechaInicio": "2017-01-05", 
              "fechaFin": "2017-01-19", 
              "genero": "0",
              "selPredefinicion": "0", 
              "formato": "csv",
              # "cadena[]": "{INTECO, ETB}",  # incorrect
              "cadena[]": ["INTECO", "ETB"]}  # <---- this is correct
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formname='formExportar', 
                                    formdata=formdata,
                                    callback=self.parse1)
```

You supplied incorrect a string instead of list here, the example above is correct and is returning/saving results properly.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this doesn' work. The file results.csv is empty after executing the crawler with your proposal. Any other solution?

Comment: @juanba1984 it does work, it's just that your response.body is empty, which means you haven't received any file data eventhough your response code is 200. Try printing it out to see if that's the case, if it is you need to adjust the crawling itself.

Comment: @juanba1984 I dug around and found the issue. The formdata bit was a bit incorrect causing all of this, see my edit.